# How to make http get request\response to site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new at web development, so how to make http request\respone for some site (http://google.com)

Thank you!

P.S.
I mean, that when my SomeController activated- i want send http request to another site,get data from it and send it into View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client (browser) submits HTTP request to the server; then the server returns a response to the client. The response contains status information about the request and also contains the requested content. GET - requests data from a specified resource, http://google.com - you type this url in browser and hit the enter key, it's a get request and you see a page, that the response.

Click **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)** for details.

Use HttpClient to connect a site from your mvc controller, click **[here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)** for details.

Comment: I mean, that when my SomeController activated- i want send http request to another site,get data from it and send it into View